# Why classical open system and Bose-Einstein condensate are not fundamentally the same?

Tags: thermodynamics, particle-physics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, bose-einstein-condensate

The classical partition function for an open system is given as
$$
Z_{\text{max}}
=
\sum_{N=0}^{\infty}
\dfrac{h^{-N}}{N! }
\prod_{j=1}^{N}
\left(
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}
e^{-\beta (E_{ij}-\mu)}
g_{i}
\right)
$$
where $E_{ij}$ is $j$th particle with in the $j$th energy state, $g_i$ is the degenecery of the $i$th energy state, $\mu$ is the chemical potential, and $N!$ is removes over-counting of indistinguishable particles.

The Bose-Einstein partition function is given as
$$
Z_{\text{bos}}
=
\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}
\left(
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}
e^{-\beta (E_{j}-\mu)i}
\right)^{g_{j}}
$$
where $j$ is evaluates all possible energies and $g_j$ is the degeneracies of the energies.

Why is it fundamentally impossible to reduce $Z_{\text{max}}$ into $Z_{\text{bos}}$, even though both systems describe particle number as not conserved? The average number of particles of both systems is given as
$$
\langle N \rangle
=
\dfrac{1}{\beta}
\dfrac{\partial \ln(Z)}{\partial \mu }
$$

Comment: crosspost to movies.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally it is that the $1/N!$ for the classical system only correctly compensates for overcounting of indistinguishable states if the particles are always in different states.  For a system of Bosons at low temperature, where it is quite likely that many particles are in the same state, this breaks down.  For a very understandable introduction to this I highly recommend the chapter on quantum statistics in the excellent thermal physics textbook by Schroeder.